# Vagrant up is stuck at Booting VM?

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I have VirtualBox (Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.3.10_Ubuntu) and vagrant (Vagrant 1.4.3) in my machine  . When I run `vagrant up` it stuck at

```
[default] Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
[default] ** Creating persistent storage **
[default] ** Attaching persistent storage **
[default] Booting VM...
```

What I have to do 
run `vagrant up`  and  `vagrant ssh`  successfully?

Comment: Try **vagrant up --debug** for debugging

Comment: Try `VBoxManage list runningvms` to see if it is running. Also try to enable VirtualBox GUI to see what happened in the console.

Comment: any luck to fix, this issue, ok? i have the same problem